# Time Series with 10min interval in R

Tags: r, time-series

I would like to create a time series with the function `ts()` but with 10 minutes interval data. My data is as follow:

```
01/10/2018 00:10    32
01/10/2018 00:20    30
01/10/2018 00:20    30
01/10/2018 00:30    31
01/10/2018 00:40    30
```

It starts at 01/10/2018 00:00 and goes to 31/05/2019 23:50 and it has 34849 rows of data. I have seen questions similar to this here but I couldn't achieve the result with it's solutions... I tried this:

```
oilT = ts(wtg01, start = c(2018,10), end = c(2019,5), deltat = 24*60/10)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

The `ts` class is not designed for this type of data. Try using the `tsibble` package instead which allows for much more general kinds of time indexed data.